# Python - Kivy: Change and keep kv file values using function from another class

Tags: python, class, kivy, global-variables, kivy-language

I am currently trying to change the values (e.g. text of a Spinner widget) of a .kv file - while changing a screen - based on the value I get from the screen before. Thats how my setup looks like (simplified):

```
mail = ''
name = ''
gender = ''
city = ''

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def get_started(self):
        global mail
        global name
        global gender
        global city
        mail = self.ids.login_mail.text
        data_person = queries.fetch_data(mail)
        name = data_person[0]
        gender = data_person[1]
        city = data_person[2]
        MainApp().change_screen('DisplayScreen')
        DisplayScreen().get_data()

class DisplayScreen(self):
    def get_data(self):
        global mail
        global name
        global gender
        global city
        self.ids.spinner_name.text = name
        self.ids.spinner_gender.text = gender
        self.ids.spinner_city.text = city
```

Class/ Screen LoginScreen does have a TextInput widget that takes an email address from a person. Then a LabelButton in the .kv file does call the root function 'get_started' which then takes the input mail of the person (ids.login_mail.text) and takes it as an argument to call the function 'fetch_data' which is located in a queries.py (Used to get values from a database). The result is a list which does contain the values name, gender, city (linked to the email address of the person). By making the variables global I tried to then call a function 'get_data' in the class/ screen DisplayScreen. DisplayScreen does contain spinners which should then automatically take the variables (name, gender, city) as the default text. The Screen should then show the three values and the person can change the values with the spinners and update his data. However it does run, does not show me any error and still does not change the spinner texts in the DisplayScreen. I think the problem is that, even if the text-update works, the screen_change does always overwrite the changes with the default values (by loading the default .kv file). In the default .kv file the spinner text is just set as 'Spinner A', 'Spinner B' and 'Spinner C'. If I put a print(name) in the DisplayScreen class before the self.ids.spinner_name.text = name update, it does correctly print me the name value in the console. So the right value is available, it just has problems with keeping the .kv file updated and not going back to default.

Screen_Change Function (defined in MainApp Class):

```
def change_screen(self, screen_name):
    screen_manager = GUI.ids['screen_manager']
    screen_manager.transition = NoTransition()
    screen_manager.current = screen_name
```

Comment: The screen change does not reload the 'kv' file, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: However, your `DisplayScreen().get_data()` is creating a new instance of `DisplayScreen` that is not displayed in your GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem. 
I got rid of the `DisPlayScreen().get_data()` function and assigned the values to my DisplayScreen already in the `LoginScreen().get_started()`.

By using `GUI.ids.display_screen.ids.spinner_name.text = name` I could access and edit the .kv file (where display_screen is the name of my kv file)

LoginScreen (just for variable name):

```
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def get_started(self):
        global mail
        mail = self.ids.login_mail.text
        global name
        data_person = queries.fetch_data(mail)
        name = data_person[0]
        GUI.ids.display_screen.ids.spinner_name.text = name
        MainApp().change_screen('DisplayScreen')
```